# What are the steps to creating a custom Service Mix distribution

Tags: apache-karaf, provisioning, apache-servicemix

ServiceMix's [documentation](http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/4.4.x/developers-guide/custom-distribution.html) on creating a custom distribution merely states the steps to creating a custom karaf distribution. I understand that Karaf is the backbone of ServiceMix and ServiceMix is a custom distribution of Karaf.

Has anyone actually built a custom esb on top of servicemix rather than on top of karaf? If so how did you do it?

How did you stage the project with servicemix's src?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some steps that I wish I had when trying to figure this out...

1. Download the sources for the version of service mix you want to build on: https://github.com/apache/servicemix/releases
2. Unpack the sources zip into any folder.
3. Create a project with the following layout:

   - MyESB

     - pom.xml
     - src

       - main
       - java
4. Copy the contents from the **pom.xml** located in **apache-service-mix-x.x.x-src/assembly** to your **pom.xml**
5. In that **pom.xml**, replace the artifactId, and name to look something like this:

```html
<parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.servicemix</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mycompany.esb</groupId>
<artifactId>mycustom-esb</artifactId>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Custom :: ESB</name>
```

- Copy the resource directories of **apache-service-mix-x.x.x-src/assembly/src/main** to **MyESB/src/main**.
- Make whatever customizations you want to the **org.apache.karaf.tooling:features-maven-plugin** or the configuratoin files in the resource directories you just copied over.

> For example, If you wanted to add a particular feature you could do the following edits to your pom.xml:
>
> - Add a features.xml to add-features-to-repo configuration descriptors
> - Add myfeature to the add-features-to-repo features list
> - To have that feature started by default, add the feature to the **featuresBoot** property located here: **MyESB\src\main\filtered-resources\etc\org.apache.karaf.features.cfg**

8. Run the maven install target! This will build a zip file into the **MyESB/target** folder. Now you can unplack that and run **servicemix.bat**
9. After starting your ESB, verify that your feature is installed by entering the following command into the Karaf console:

   > features:list | grep myfeature

Answer (score 0):

Well, just do it like servicemix itself it does. And tbh it's just the way it's described in the Karaf documentation. 
For an example you might want to look [here](https://github.com/apache/servicemix/blob/master/assembly/pom.xml#L134)

In short define it in your custom assembly POM, take a look at the following snippet:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${karaf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-features-to-repo</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>features-add-to-repository</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/${karaf.version}/xml/features</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/${karaf.version}/xml/features</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring/${karaf.version}/xml/features</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/${activemq.version}/xml/features</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/${camel.version}/xml/features</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/${cxf.version}/xml/features</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>file:${basedir}/target/classes/internal.xml</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>file:${basedir}/target/classes/features.xml</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>file:${basedir}/target/classes/examples.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <features>
                            <feature>cxf</feature>
                            <feature>obr</feature>
                            <feature>config</feature>
                            <feature>standard</feature>
                            <feature>package</feature>
                            <feature>kar</feature>
                            <feature>ssh</feature>
                            <feature>management</feature>
                            <feature>eventadmin</feature>
                            <feature>activemq-broker-noweb</feature>
                            <feature>activemq-service</feature>
                            <feature>camel</feature>
                            <feature>camel-cxf</feature>
                            <feature>activemq-camel</feature>
                            <feature>camel-blueprint</feature>
                            <feature>war</feature>
                            <feature>jaxrs-api</feature>
                        </features>
                        <includeMvnBasedDescriptors>true</includeMvnBasedDescriptors>
                        <repository>target/features-repo</repository>
                    </configuration>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

If you need your own custom bundles/features make sure you
a) have a feature descriptor for your own bundles
b) define the feature *descriptor*
c) tell the plugin to use the corresponding *feature*

Comment: Thanks for answering, but It's still unclear to me where to start. Do I download ServiceMix's source and modify the root level pom.xml or do I start with an empty project and use maven to import the service mix source? When I download servicemix's source and try to build, even before any modifications, it fails.

Comment: No need to download the sources, just create a custom assembly project which contains a pom as shown. The Karaf plugging will take care of it. As said add your own feature descriptor or the missing descriptors to the plugin configuration.